# C++ Acessing Array Elements Several Times

Tags: c++, arrays, element

I'm very new to C++ but have been programming in less hard core languages (java, python) for a couple of years. I just encountered a very weird error in my code and am looking for an explaination and a solution.

I have created an array of doubles in a function, returned a pointer and am now trying to access the elemts of the array. I can access any element just fine as you would, `arr[i]`, but as I try to access a second element (yes "a" second, not "the" second) everything goes very wrong. Sometimes I get zero and the rest of the time I get very big numbers (close to the the biggest double which isn't infinity, 1.7...10^308).´

As I understand accessing a position in the array which isn't actually in the array should render these kind of results but even running `cout<<arr[1]<<", "<<arr[0];` prints first what's expected and then something very unreasonable.

I am really trying to properly understand what's going on so any help is appreciated but remember I am very new to C++, thanks.

-----EDIT-----

Here's what gives me the problem:

```
double* fun(){
    double arr[] = {3.14, 2.7, 1.0};
    return arr;
}

int main(){
    double* arr = fun();
    cout<<arr[1]<<", "<<arr[0]<<endl;

    return 0;
}

/* Prints "2.7, 0" */
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with a [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Returning Arrays/Pointers from a function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5378768/returning-arrays-pointers-from-a-function)

Comment: switch the third line to `return &arr[0];`

Comment: @ocket8888 thanks but this unfortunately doesn't fix it. Even printing arr[0] twice gives "3.14, 0".

Comment: No, you misunderstand. I'll write an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not allowed to return a pointer to the stack-allocated variable (or to the array) because it leads to the undefined behaviour. You should allocate your array at the heap via `new`:

```
double *fun(){
    double *arr = new double[3];
    arr[0] = 1;
    arr[1] = - 123.45;
    arr[2] = 42;

    return arr;
}
```

Or you can use a standard container for a static array, which is even better and much more convenient:

```
#include <array>

std::array<double, 3> fun(){
    std::array<double, 3> result = {3.14, 2.7, 1.0};
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Well yeah, you _can_ do that, if you want it to compile without warnings and run without segfaulting. But there's no way the `std::` way is better or more convenient.

Comment: @ocket8888 In terms of language everything what leads to the undefined behaviour is prohibited. But compilers don't care, so..

Comment: Thanks, this finally fixed it but I understand that I should `free(arr)` if I use the conventional C++ arrays. Am I right and in this case what does that really do?

Comment: no, use `delete` in C++. What I posted was wrong because of that, and I changed it before you commented, but apparently not until after you tried it. That will de-allocate the memory, otherwise other programs won't be able to use that memory, even after you're done with it.

Comment: @IvarEriksson It's bad to create an object in one place and destroy it in another, but yes, you should free this memory via `delete[] arr;`.

Comment: Another possibility is to declare the variable as `static` within the function.  The `static` keyword makes the variable hang around until the program terminates.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Worst antipattern I've ever seen :D

Comment: @LibertyPaul What? Thomas Matthews solution works perfectly, and provided the memory is freed as soon as it's not needed it's not wasting anything. Plus, not `delete`ing the array as soon as you don't need it, even if that's outside the function, is totally bad practice.

Comment: @ocket8888 Yes, it woks like a vast of shitty examples (Welcome to C/C++ :-)) But anyway you shouldn't do that.

Comment: Why not? That's what `static` is for, outside of class definitions.

Answer (score 0):

In C++, you can technically access elements in an array that are un-allocated. Other languages, such as Java actually prevent you from doing this. If it is giving you back junk values, you are accessing un-allocated space. Make sure you check your bounds. For example:

```
double array[10];
cout << array[100]; // gives back junk value because it was not allocated. You need to stay within the index values 0 - 9.
```

works... but

```
double array[10];
cin >> array[100];  // Cause an error. Seg fault most likely
```

will give you back an error.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question

Answer (score -2):

The problem is that the array is created on the stack and that a pointer to this object is returned. Basically you are returning a [dangling pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer).

To solve this you need to allocate memory for the array:

```
double* fun() {
    auto arr = new double[3]{ 3.14, 2.7, 1.0 };
    return arr;
}
```

Keep in mind that you need to free the memory. A better approach would be to use [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) or [std::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) for fixed-size array. The heap memory for those objects will safely be managed by the object's lifetime (RAII).

```
std::array<double,3> fun() {
    return { 3.14, 2.7, 1.0 };
}
```

or using vector:

```
std::vector<double> fun() {
    return { 3.14, 2.7, 1.0 };
}
```

Comment: Copying other's answers is BAD

Comment: @LibertyPaul I did not do that on purpose? Seems like there is only one right answer to this question anyway!

Comment: You have got one from me because of plagiarism

Comment: @LibertyPaul from where?